# How to store an uploaded swf file in a MySQL database using PHP? 

Tags: php, mysql

How do I store an uploaded swf file in a MySQL database using PHP?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to store the file on disk, and then store the metadata (like filename, and possibly other fields such as uploader) in the database. This way you will get a faster database, because you don't need to have large BLOB fields in the table, and you will also serve the files faster since they can be read directly from disk instead of sent through the MySQL connection over the network.

So when the file is uploaded, give it a unique filename and store it in a folder on disk. Then store metadata (including the unique filename) in the database. If you have trouble defining a unique filename, just save the metadata first and have an AUTOINCREMENTed column in the database that you use as filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here u can upload swf files also 

<?php
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
 define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file  is an image by checking the extension.
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif") && ($extension != "swf")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}}


//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";


 }

 ?>

 <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" and use an input type "file" -->
 <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
 <table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
 </table>   
 </form>
```